# google-wallet subscriptions JWT array sequence order

Tags: php, arrays, android-pay, jwt

my code produces a token array which is in the order required for the jwt however when i run the encode script it is re-sequenced to an alphabetical order. This causes a failure when submitted to google. It looks like the sequence is reordered with assort function but is not. I expect the explode implode functions are causing this but i cant see a way to fix!

the echoed array "$Token" is:-

```
 Array ( [iss] => 12345605871924644272 
    [aud] => Google 
    [typ] => google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1 
    [exp] => 1414875564 
    [iat] => 1414871964
    [request]     => array ( [name] => Invoice Number: 106599 
                             [description] => Supported Service 
                             [sellerData] =>user_id:1224245,
                                offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j
       [initialPayment] => Array( [price] => 100 
                                  [currencyCode] => GBP
                                  [paymentType] => prorated ) 
       [recurrence] => Array ( [price] => 30 
                               [currencyCode] => GBP
                               [startTime] => 3600 [frequency] => Monthly
                               [numRecurrences] => 24 
              )
            ) 
       )
```

the jwt encode function is then called with

```
  $jwtToken = JWT::encode($Token, $sellerSecretKey);
```

the script function called is

```
  public static function encode($payload, $key, $algo = 'HS256')
 {
    $header = array('typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => $algo);

    $segments = array();
    $segments[] = JWT::urlsafeB64Encode(JWT::jsonEncode($header));
    $segments[] = JWT::urlsafeB64Encode(JWT::jsonEncode($payload));
    $signing_input = implode('.', $segments);

    $signature = JWT::sign($signing_input, $key, $algo);
    $segments[] = JWT::urlsafeB64Encode($signature);

    return implode('.', $segments);
 }

 /**
 * @param string $msg    The message to sign
 * @param string $key    The secret key
 * @param string $method The signing algorithm
 *
 * @return string An encrypted message
 */
 public static function sign($msg, $key, $method = 'HS256')
 {
    $methods = array(
        'HS256' => 'sha256',
        'HS384' => 'sha384',
        'HS512' => 'sha512',
    );
    if (empty($methods[$method])) {
        throw new DomainException('Algorithm not supported');
    }
    return hash_hmac($methods[$method], $msg, $key, true);
 }
```

The returned jwt has the correct elements but in the wrong sequence. the desired sequence is shown first and mine after

```
{
"iss" : "1337133713371337",
"aud" : "Google",
"typ" : "google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1",
"exp" : "1309988959",
"iat" : "1409988959",
"request" :{
  "name" : "Weekly Cake",
  "description" : "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy every week",
  "sellerData" : "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j",
  "initialPayment" : {
    "price" : "1.49",
    "currencyCode" : "USD",
    "paymentType" : "prorated",
  },
  "recurrence" : {
    "price" : "4.99",
    "currencyCode" : "USD",
    "startTime" : "1309989638",
    "frequency" : "monthly",
    "numRecurrences" : "12",
  }
}
}
```

mine

```
{
"aud": "Google", 
"iss": "12345605871924644272", 
"request": {
    "initialPayment": {
        "paymentType": "prorated", 
        "price": "100", 
        "currencyCode": "GBP"
    }, 
    "recurrence": {
        "numRecurrences": "24", 
        "price": "30", 
        "frequency": "Monthly", 
        "currencyCode": "GBP", 
        "startTime": "3600"
    }, 
    "sellerData": "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j", 
    "name": "Invoice Number: 106599", 
    "description": "Supported Service"
}, 
"exp": 1414873724, 
"iat": 1414870124, 
"typ": "google/payments/inapp/subscription/v1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order shouldn't matter. Look into your `startTime` value (`3600`).

> startTime: Number.
>
> *Optional*. Time in seconds from epoch to start recurring the charge. The first recurrence will occur at the time specified in this field.

Hth...

Comment: thanks EdSF I have increased start time by x100 just in case but I still get the same error if the oder doesn't matter then i can't see anything else as the single item works and the  type has been changed togoogle/payments/inapp/subscription/v1

Comment: @Dave Look at how you generate `exp` and `iat` ('nix epoch) - it should be the same for `startTime`. e.g. `1417564800` means your `startTime` for `recurrence` will be `Wed, 03 Dec 2014 00:00:00 GMT` Hth...

Comment: the code used is  $payload->SetIssuedAt(time());
           $payload->SetExpiration(time()+3600); This the same as used successfully in the single item. I have assumed current time is being returned   and start time for recurrence in iat plus starttime in seconds. Am I correct?

Comment: @dave Apologies, I misspoke - I meant you have to convert the time to epoch value for `startTime` just as you are doing for `iat` and `exp`. In your code above, you set your `startTime` to `3600` which is `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 GMT` (invalid)

Comment: OK changed start time to time()+2592000 and it now works!!!!!! with first subscription showing as 2014 /12/03. All i need now is my postback working and I'll have fully integrated to wallet using PHP!!